# How to count documents using stored fields only in Apache solr

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, nutch

I am using solr 4.10.3. Documents are indexed using apache nutch 2.3. There is a field in schema.xml that is tstamp that contains informas when documents was indexed. This field  is not indexed and stored only in solr. I want to count no of documents indexed by nutch in solr. It is clear that I have to use tstamp field. Now how I can do it?

Please explain in details.

Answer (score 0):

The default **nutch-default.xml** config file does not have the index-more plugin activated. You can enable it by adding it to the plugin chain.

Look for the plugin.includes property and change it from

`<value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>`

to

`<value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor|more)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>`

**index-more** will index the fetch date.
Now to know the total number of documents being indexed you need to do a Solr query.

All documents: `*:*`

Documents indexed in the last 24 hours: `date:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW]`